# Merging k sorted linked lists - analysis

Tags: algorithm, merge, list

I am thinking about different solutions for one problem. Assume we have K sorted linked lists and we are merging them into one. All these lists together have N elements.

The well known solution is to use priority queue and pop / push first elements from every lists and I can understand why it takes `O(N log K)` time.

But let's take a look at another approach. Suppose we have some `MERGE_LISTS(LIST1, LIST2)` procedure, that merges two sorted lists and it would take `O(T1 + T2)` time, where `T1` and `T2` stand for `LIST1` and `LIST2` sizes.

What we do now generally means pairing these lists and merging them pair-by-pair (if the number is odd, last list, for example, could be ignored at first steps). This generally means we have to make the following "tree" of merge operations:

`N1, N2, N3...` stand for `LIST1, LIST2, LIST3` sizes

- `O(N1 + N2) + O(N3 + N4) + O(N5 + N6) + ...`
- `O(N1 + N2 + N3 + N4) + O(N5 + N6 + N7 + N8) + ...`
- `O(N1 + N2 + N3 + N4 + .... + NK)`

*It looks obvious that there will be `log(K)` of these rows, each of them implementing `O(N)` operations, so time for `MERGE(LIST1, LIST2, ... , LISTK)` operation would actually equal `O(N log K)`.*

***My friend told me (two days ago) it would take `O(K N)` time. So, the question is - did I f%ck up somewhere or is he actually wrong about this? And if I am right, why this 'divide&conquer' approach can't be used instead of priority queue approach?***

Comment: Hm, I guess it's worse than the priority_queue algo because it uses a lot of additional memory. Still, it's easier to implement... Hm :)

Comment: `N` in this problem defines the total number of elements in ALL lists, not the average number of elements for one of the lists.

Comment: I can understand there will be logK number of rows, but can you please explain why each row is O(n)? For example, in the first row, wouldn't there be k*O(n)?

Comment: There would be N*K elements that would be touched upon no matter what strategy you use. So, complexity can not be brought down from O(N*K).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a small number of lists to merge, this pairwise scheme is likely to be faster than a priority queue method because you have extremely few operations per merge: basically just one compare and two pointer reassignments per item (to shift into a new singly-linked list).  As you've shown, it is `O(N log K)` (`log K` steps handling `N` items each).

But the best priority queue algorithms are, I believe, `O(sqrt(log K))` or `O(log log U)` for insert and remove (where `U` is the number of possible different priorities)--if you can prioritize with a value instead of having to use a compare--so if you are merging items that can be given e.g. integer priorities, and `K` is large, then you're better off with a priority queue.

Comment: I actually think it's worth profiling. This theoretical analysis may sometimes benefit, but generally I'll now try to determine after what K does my approach begin to lack comparing to priority queue approach. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

From your description, it does sound like your process is indeed O(N log K). It also will work, so you can use it.

I personally would use the first version with a priority queue, since I suspect it will be faster. It's not faster in the coarse big-O sense, but I think if you actually work out the number of comparisons and stores taken by both, the second version will take several times more work.

Answer (score 1):

This is `O(2*log(K)*N)` this is `O(N*log(K))` and you can't have worst complexity because you only `2N` times add to priority queue in `O(log(K))`.

Or you can push all elements into vector in `O(2N)`. And sort it in `O(2n*log(2n))`. Then you have `O(2N+2N*Log(2N))`, this is `O(N*LOG(N))`, exacly your `K = N`;

Comment: Generally speaking, I only wanted to know if I'm right in my analysis, without taking the constants before `N log K` in account. Probably, if this would be a bottleneck place in my code, I would use the priority queue algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

It runs indeed in `O(N*log K)`, but don't forget, that `O(N*log K)` is a subset of `O(N*K)`. I.e. your friend is not wrong either.

Comment: Looks like a brilliant way to save our friendship :))