# Is This an Efficient Way to Sort Multiple Linked Lists?

Tags: java, list, linked-list

You have n sorted linked lists, each of size n. The linked lists references
are stored in an array. What is an efficient algorithm to merge the n linked
lists into a single sorted linked list?

Since they are all sorted:

1. Incorporate a loop
2. Check the first node of all the sorted linked lists and sort them by comparing to each other.
3. Proceed to next node and repeat until `null` is hit.

Is this the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Missing assumptions: are the elements in the linked list contiguous with each other, or interleaved?  `{{1,2,3,5}, {4,7,9,11}}` would be valid/invalid?  Do I have 3 linked lists with 3 elements apiece? (Clarifying that n.)

Comment: yes separate each linked list is already sorted and has the exact same number of elements..

Comment: So interleaving is OK then too?

Comment: no i would suppose they are contiguous in the list.

Comment: Keyword: "N-way merge" (with tweaks for a linked list), e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055909/algorithm-for-n-way-merge , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705366/merging-k-sorted-linked-lists-analysis should be `O(N*K)` time.

Comment: I think the title should be "Efficient way to *Merge* multiple *Sorted* Lists?"

Comment: (While N-way merge is the generic approach for this, I think Makoto is onto something ... if they are continuous min/max runs can be utilized.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging k sorted linked lists - analysis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705366/merging-k-sorted-linked-lists-analysis)

Answer (score 0):

Just link them all together (or dump them into a single list) and use a general sort.  That will give you nlog(n) performance.  Your way is n^2.

Comment: if you dump all the lists into an array in his example then it is n^2 (n lists of size n)

Comment: @DavidCheung No, it only takes linear time to put all the elements into a list.  Yes, the list will have size of n^2, but it will only take nlogn time to sort.

Comment: yes but you will be reading n lists of size n (n*n) to read through all the lists and form one large array, the full algorithm complexity is n^2 + nlogn which makes it n^2

Comment: You could do it very efficiently by just linking the last of the first to the first of the second, etc.

Comment: This can be done better since the *lists are already sorted*. It's just a N-way merge.